# how to update the object using its instance in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a `n` number of nested array which is showing its data in html recursion in angular. now i have to update some data by selecting
particular field, if there is direct edit then there is no problem in updating for that i used just variable instance

```
arr=[{
    "name":"field-1",
    "fields":[
        {
            "name":"Field-2",
            "fields":[]
        },
        {
            "name":"field-3",
            "fields":[
                {
                    "name":"field-3",
                    "fields":[]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

if i want to edit one field i've done simply assigning its instance to a variable

```html
<ng-template #recursion let-data="data">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
        <div>
            {{item.name}}
            <button (click)="edithThis(item)">Edit</button>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="item.fields && item.fields.length">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursion;context:{data:item.fields}"></ng-container>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

```
export class Component{

    data_to_edit: any;

    edithThis(selected: any) {
        this.data_to_edit=selected
    }

}
```

if i modified the `data_to_edit` the original value is modifying, now i have cancel also, when he click on the cancel the changes need to revert
back to his old value, for that i tried by taking two variables.

```
export class Component {

    data_to_edit: any;
    instance_of_data: any;

    edithThis(selected: any) {
        this.data_to_edit = { ...selected }
        this.instance_of_data = selected
    }

}
```

one will use to modify his value, but after modifying i need to update the original value once he conforms the change.

Comment: you can keep a clone if cancel is pressed you can replace it with clone. you can clone it by const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); somewhere where you first receive the data

Comment: Yeah ‘this.data_to_edit’ this is my clone object but i have to update the value once he click confirm in nth level of nested array.

Comment: you need to deep clone else references of object will still be there use the code in above comment to clone it

Comment: i need reference for it, i have to update the data at reference, because i don't have the exact location in nested array of the value.

Answer (score 0):

right now i'm storing the data in two values, one is for the editing data,
another is for its reference (which can be used to update its value in heap memory). after click on confirm i'm updating the reference with simple loop

```
export class Component {

    data_to_edit: any;
    instance_of_data: any;

    edithThis(selected: any) {
        this.data_to_edit = { ...selected }; // without reference
        this.instance_of_data = selected; // storing for reference
    }

    /**
     * updates the reference of variable with edited data
     */
    updateData() {
        for (let key in this.instance_of_data) { // for all old keys
            if (!(key in this.data_to_edit)) { // if there is a key removal while editing, remove the key from its reference 
                delete this.instance_of_data[key]
            } else { // else update its reference value with the current data
                this.instance_of_data[key] = this.data_to_edit[key]
            }
        }
    }

}
```

if he click on cancel i can neglect the changes.
i'm open for other approaches. thankyou.